# how to search index from another dataframe columns by passing dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes df1 and df2.

```
df1
index     emp_id     name         code 
  0          07       emp07        'A'      
  1          11       emp11        'B'      
  2          30       emp30        'C'  

df2
index       emp_id   salary 
     0      06       1000            
     1      17       2000             
     2      11       3000
```

I want to store a map from `df1['emp_id']` to `df2.index`.

Example: input array - ['emp11','B'] (from df1)

Expected output: `[11, 2]  # this is df1['emp_id'], df2.index`

Code I am trying:

```
columns_to_idx = {emp_id: i for i, emp_id in 
    enumerate(list(DF1.set_index('emp_id').loc[DF2.index][['name', 'code']]))}
```

Comment: Related: [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 4):

I think you need [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with inner join and [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for column from index for avoid lost it:

```
df = df1.merge(df2.reset_index(), on='emp_id')
print (df)
   emp_id   name code  index  salary
0      11  emp11   B      2    3000
```

Then is possible create `MultiIndex` and select by tuple:

```
df2 = (df1.merge(df2.reset_index(), on='emp_id')
         .set_index(['name','code'])[['emp_id','index']])
print (df2)
            emp_id  index
name  code               
emp11 B         11      2

print (df2.loc[('emp11','B')].tolist())
[11, 2]
```

Comment: It helps to explain to the OP why `merge` does what they need, and why not the other pandas commands. Related: [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)